# Use woocomerce shop filters on other pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I can’t do a page with filters like shop.
I want to do a page with promotional products similar as shop page but filters doesnt work and I can´t

This is a image of my shop page : [image]

This is a image of my promotional products page: [image]

I also can’t also put breadcrumbs on that page like the shop page.

This is a image of the WPbakery Page Builder: [image]

And this is a image of my widget area: [image]

Comment: How are the products coming on promotional products page? have you used any category or added the products manually?

Comment: I'm using "woocomerce sale products" widget.

Comment: i found this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112648/is-there-a-way-to-display-woocommerce-nav-filter-widget-filters-for-shop-page-in?rq=1
but i dont know exactly what is the files to edit